# Report to Show Which Profiles an App is Associated to

Tags: community, profile, appexchange

Is there a way I can extract data from Data Loader to show which Profiles are associated to my 3rd party app?  The reason is because, the app was deleted in my Sandbox and I have to reinstall it.  I want to mirror the exact setup as production in regard to profiles and page layout.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data Loader is for *data*, not things like page layouts and profiles, which are mostly in the realm of *metadata*. Instead, you'll want to use Ant, Force.com IDE, Mavensmate, etc, to grab the installed package (which will include all of its components), plus your profiles, then deploy the package to your sandbox. You'll need to install the package first before attempting to deploy the profiles.